# Is it possible to display Admob native ad to a React Native project?

Tags: react-native

I have searched the web but can not find a plugin to do this. There are several plugins that support "banner" and "interstitial", but no support for "[native](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express)".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an [open issue](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/24) regarding this since July 2016. Since it doesn't seem to be supported yet, I think the only solution would be to write your own custom [Native UI Component for Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html) that exposes a `NativeExpressAdView` to React Native.